# Deliberate destruction of a person with drugs. A synonym to chemical lobotomy?

Tags: phrase-request

The author Susan Lindauder alleges that some inmates at an institution are forcefully administered with heavy drugs like Haldol, Ativan etc., until their brain functions are damaged to such a degree that they cannot speak or walk.

One term, describing this procedure, which Ms Lindauer mentions in a speech, is "chemical lobotomizing." I wonder what other verbal phrases could be used here? In some languages "***reducing a person to a vegetable***" could be used ... but would "*reducing a person to a vegetable*" sound good in the English? And what other phrases could be used here instead?

Answer (score 3):

[Vegetable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vegetable) is used to describe a person's state in English as well:

> a person whose mental and physical functioning is severely impaired and especially one who requires supportive measures (as mechanical ventilation) to survive

but it is mostly used to describe certain patients in a hospital. Not someone/something you would encounter at a prison facility.